# Filter kafka stream by topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Filter Kafka steam of multiple topics by topic.

```
kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zookeeper_server, groupId='group-0', topics={'topic1': 1,'topic2': 1}, valueDecoder=lambda v: json.loads(v))
```

I like to filter the stream by topic1 and topic2, let's say it kafka_stream_topic1 and kafka_steeam_topic2 and then process it separately.

```
 kafka_stream_topic1.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(process_func_for_topic1))
 kafka_stream_topic2.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(process_func_for_topic2))
```

Filter stream by each topic and then process separately.

Comment: I think you are supposed to put a question here.

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati There was some confusion with new template, I like to achieve filtering by topic.